# Работа с ORM Django отдельно

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-orm

Пишу скрипт для обработки некоторых даных, и мне нужно получить эти данные с БД. Скрипт пишу не в `views.py`. Скрипт находится в `myscript.py`. Хотел импортировать модели, как обычно в `views.py`, но оно стало матюкатся. Порылся в инете, узнал что если нужно, например, работать отельно с ORM, в отдельном файле, то нужно прописывать `django.setup()`. Но просто так же его не пропишешь, там еще настройки проекта нужно подлючать. Подскажите пожалуйста, как все это сделать, что прописать чтобы потом нормально работать с ORM Django.

Вот структура проекта:

```
[name_project]
├── [name_project]
│   ├── settings
│   |   ├── __init__.py
│   |   ├── _django.py
|   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
├── myapp
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── myscript.py
└── manage.py
```

Comment: [Документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings). В вашем случае `Settings.py` не видно. Вероятно, перед `django.setup()` поможет `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "name_project.settings._django.py")`. Также [альтернатива](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/#using-settings-without-setting-django-settings-module)

Comment: @m9_psy сделал первое то что вы написали. выкинуло `ImportError: No module named 'name_project'` . вместо `name_project` прописал название своего проекта)

Comment: А зачем вам свой отдельный скрипт? Почему бы не добавить дополнительную команду в штатную запускалку Django через `manage.py`? [Документация про это](http://djbook.ru/rel1.9/howto/custom-management-commands.html)

Comment: @andreymal благодарствую) реально легче так сделать.